# Losing data when sending between two classes

Tags: java, android, function, oop, arraylist

My app doesn't display anything when passing data from one class to another. I located through with the debugger that my ArrayList doesn't get the right value from the class.
I'm sending data with the following function:

```
public class Adaugare extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView myListView;
private NumeAdapter numeAdapter;
String inume;
int ivarsta;
Intent intent = new Intent();
private ArrayList persoanaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList getPersoanaArrayList() {
    return persoanaArrayList;
}

public int getPersoanaArrayListsize() {
    return persoanaArrayList.size();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adaugare);

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.persoana_list);

    Button btn_fin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fin);
    btn_fin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText nume_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ins_nume);
            EditText varsta_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ins_var);

            ivarsta = Integer.parseInt(varsta_edit_text.getText().toString());
            inume = nume_edit_text.getText().toString();

            persoanaArrayList.add(new Persoana(inume, ivarsta));
        }
    });
}
```

}

And recieving it with:

```
public class Afisare extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView myListView;
NumeAdapter numeAdapter;
Adaugare ad = new Adaugare();
int cate;
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_afisare);

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.persoana_list);
    ArrayList<Persoana> persoanaArrayList = new ArrayList<Persoana>(ad.getPersoanaArrayList());
    numeAdapter = new NumeAdapter(this, persoanaArrayList);
    myListView.setAdapter(numeAdapter);
}
```

The class Persoana is:

```
public class Persoana {
private String nume;
private int varsta;

Persoana(String inume, int ivar) {
    this.nume = inume;
    this.varsta = ivar;
}

public String getNume() {
    return nume;
}

public int getVarsta() {
    return varsta;
}

public void setNume(String nume) {
    this.nume = nume;
}

public void setVarsta(int varsta) {
    this.varsta = varsta;
}
```

}

*Persoana* is the main class, everything is saved in it. *ad* is an object of *Adaugare*, *Adaugare* being the class from which I've taken the code for *getPersoanaArrayList*. At debugging some values appeared at *ad*, namely *Adaugare @4556*, and *persoanaArrayList* remains *null*.
I need the *persoanaArrayList* so that i can initialize my Adapter and listView. Everything else in the code seems fine from step by step testing with debugger.

Comment: show all your code related to the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you, but we are not clairvoyant. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54963390/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: `Adaugare ad = new Adaugare();` As far as I'm aware of: this is not how you should create a new class in this context, for `onCreate` of `Adaugare` won't be called and its list won't be filled.

Comment: If you tag this as Android related I feel you will get better support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the following line in the Afisare class:

```
Adaugare ad = new Adaugare();
```

You can't simply new one activity from another activity and expect to access a shared list between them.  To share instance data between java objects you need a reference to the other object.  Creating a new instance will create a new empty list. That's why you are "losing" data.  A quick fix would be to make the list static so it can be accessed from any instance.

But since you're dealing with Android, the right way to share data between activities is by using intent extras. The first activity starts the second activity via an intent. The first activity places the desired data in the intent as extras. The second activity uses getIntent() and the various methods on Intent to access the extras.

One last tip, in Android, you never use the new operator with Activities. Activities are created by the system to service an intent. If you find yourself using the new operator, that's a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: So I've went with your option of using intent. I'm sending an intent in "Adaugare" and receiving it in "Afisare" but at "myListView.setAdapter(NumeAdapter)" it crashes. I can't find why, but adding that part of code in comment i found out that this line it is faulty.